# postgress import data from a database to another one which has tables with more columns

Tags: postgresql

I have two postgres 9.6 databases on different machines:

- db1 - older version with the data I need
- db2 - the schema was updated and now it contains more columns. I only use the schema here. I don't need the data

I would like to bring all the data from db1 to db2 which has the newer schema. There are quite a few tables and I wouldn't want to alter them manually.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use copy command with column name specified copy table_name (column...) to ....  and copy table_name (column...) from ...

Copy to for export and copy from for import
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-copy.html

```
COPY { table_name [ ( column_name [, ...] ) ] | ( query ) }
TO { 'filename' | STDOUT }
[ [ WITH ]
      [ BINARY ]
      [ OIDS ]
      [ DELIMITER [ AS ] 'delimiter' ]
      [ NULL [ AS ] 'null string' ]
      [ CSV [ HEADER ]
            [ QUOTE [ AS ] 'quote' ]
            [ ESCAPE [ AS ] 'escape' ]
            [ FORCE QUOTE { column_name [, ...] | * } ] ] ]

COPY table_name [ ( column_name [, ...] ) ]
FROM { 'filename' | STDIN }
[ [ WITH ]
      [ BINARY ]
      [ OIDS ]
      [ DELIMITER [ AS ] 'delimiter' ]
      [ NULL [ AS ] 'null string' ]
      [ CSV [ HEADER ]
            [ QUOTE [ AS ] 'quote' ]
            [ ESCAPE [ AS ] 'escape' ]
            [ FORCE NOT NULL column_name [, ...] ] ] ]
```